# Firebase Query don't show data

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have the next structure in firebase:

```
  {
  "crisoftcalendar" : {
    "usuarios" : {
      "-Jx3DKK8QsWGzdfowdAR" : {
        "listaUsuario" : [ {
          "nombre" : "hijo1 prueba",
          "usuario" : "hijo1mauricio@email.com"
        }, {
          "nombre" : "hijo2 prueba",
          "usuario" : "hijo2mauricio@email.com"
        } ],
        "nombre" : "prueba",
        "usuario" : "mauricio@email.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in javascript I have the next 'query'

```
ref2.startAt('mauricio@email.com').endAt('mauricio@email.com').on('value', function(snap) {
        console.log("name '" + snap.key() + "' val = " + snap.val());
        snap.forEach(function(data) {
        console.log("clave '" + data.key() + "'' valor = " + data.val().usuario);
      });
    });
```

I want get the user with email *mauricio@email.com* but in the console don't show nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the orderByChild and specify the field you want to query on and the equalTo as there would only be one matching record

```
ref.orderByChild("usuario").equalTo('mauricio@email.com').on('value',
     function(snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot.key())
});
```